# Detect commercial in Spotify App API

Tags: spotify

Is there any way to detect if a commercial is playing? I'm using

```
player.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE, function (event)
```

to detect when a new song is played. The problem is that this event occurs when a commercial is played too.

(Hard to test if you have a developer account tied to the premium service without commercials.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Track class appears to have a hidden property called **isAd**, which can be accessed like `track.data.isAd`, which presumably would contain the data you want (you can see this property and others by using `console.log(track)` in your app.

As this property is undocumented, I'm not sure whether it is acceptable to use this it in a published app. Somebody from Spotify would need to answer that one.